# How to comment inside a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, comments

```
$var = "a
  b // I want to comment here but it becomes a string instead
  c"
```

I want to insert a comment in the middle of multiple line string in PHP, but I can't. I've tried `/**/`, `//`, and `#`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: you can't have, since string is a constant.

Comment: It's important. To point out where the error lies for an SQL query string for example.

Comment: so then you can use SQL comment in php string like this SELECT * FROM orders -- comment WHERE p <  25 or you may use # instead of --

Comment: That's helpful. Should make it into a different question post sometime.

Comment: Unless your comment specifically needs to be read in another context (you cite SQL as an example, but it's questionable to me how helpful having the comment inline would be), your code sample makes the comment non-obvious to someone reading this code in this context. The concatenation answers below are better, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a case where this could possibly add clarity instead of taking it away. If you find yourself having to do something like this, back up and take a look at why this has become "important." There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: It can easily be done in Python. What's wrong with PHP?

Comment: @kungphu Sometimes complex queries are helped by inline comments. I know I have a tricky regex with comments in the string itself (using the `x` modifier to allow it and generous whitespace)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just comment then have the string. e.g. //my comment newline $var = "a string";

Comment: @akshaykhale: Your comment does not make sense to me.

Comment: @akshaykhale: That makes even less sense :|

Comment: @phresnel sorry, I didn't ready your comment properly...

Comment: @phresnel the person asking question was looking for some way to add SQL comments withing PHP string that's why I provided that solution which make sense for him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$var = "a
  b ".// I want to comment here but it becomes a string instead."  
  "c";

echo $var;
```

Comment: Ugh, that's not commenting within a string. Please at least clarify to the asker what you are doing, since as it is, it looks like you are promoting `".//` as the "string commenting operator".

Comment: if u know the answer for this then paste it..we will also get knw the correct answer

Comment: The correct answer was given already. No need to be redundant. Why not edit your answer to make it better, instead of falling back to being miffed?

Comment: @SebastianMach Bit late, but I just submitted an edit that was six years overdue. So hopefully that’s better and gets approved

Answer (score 9):

Only possible with concatenation and a comment:

```
$var = "a\n" .
//     "b\n" .
       "c";
```

Comment: This is not useful as its not printing "b". @Scopey

Comment: Ha sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought the "b" wanted to be commented out. Accepted answer is the way i'd do this.

Answer (score 2):

you can also write your code like this. If you want multi line you can use `\n` at after string.

```
$string = 'First';
$string .= 'Comment section ';//this where you can comment
$string .= 'Last';
```

Comment: Nice to know that. Finally, I know `.=` is possible.

Comment: Yes, @Aminah Nuraini you can achieve your task with concatenation

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$var = "a\n" .
"b\n" . //this where you can comment
"c";
echo $var;
?>
```

**Output**

```
a
b
c
```

**Check code and output in editor. [Click Here](https://eval.in/551890)**

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer but I thought I'll share my 2 cents as well:
You could use the HTML comment tag:

```
<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->
```

The catch is that users can view this comment if they view source!

With the example you gave:

```
$var = "a
  b <!--I want to comment here but it becomes a string instead-->
  c";
```

And while we're at it, you can use /**/ inside Style tag(**CSS**):

```
.Class {
  width: 100%; /*The width*/
}
```

Or as someone already suggested just close the string and comment inside **PHP**:

```
$var = "a".
       "b". //Comment
       "c";
```

And if you want to maintain the **new line**:

```
$var = "a\n"
```

Comment: The first solution won't work if I the string as an SQL query